# Extract randomly formatted year from string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect the year in a string. I've looked at a lot of other previously asked questions, but cannot find one which addresses random formats. Let's say I'm searching for a part for a 2001 Ford Explorer and I want to filter the results to remove parts which are not for that year. I may encounter the below year formats. I thought String.contains("01") would be OK, but then that also matches 2010, and doesn't address when the year I'm searching for isn't in the string at all, but would fall between other years. Is it possible that one regex could cover all of these scenarios?

- Fits 2001 Ford Explorer.
- Fits 1997-2002 Ford Explorer.
- Fits 01 Ford Explorer.
- 01 Ford Explorer.
- Fits 97-02 Ford Explorer.
- Fits 97 thru(or through)02 Ford Explorer.

#### Attempt

```
public Boolean filterResult(String str, String expectedYear){
if(str.contains("expectedYear") && (str.indexOf(expectedYear)-1 !=2 || 
str.indexOf(expectedYear) == 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

In case of 2010 returns false. Returns true if the previous digit was a space or dash, and also if expectedYear falls at the beginning of the string.
Doesn't address expectedYear being between two other years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2})
```

However, this will just detect if the pattern matches.  You will need to add more logic to make sure it is valid.

Check this at: https://rubular.com

[image]

Comment: Wow, that tool is amazing. Seeing what the regex is doing makes all the difference in the world. I can see how I could use that regex to detect what is likely to be the year, and then validate it. I could see where I would get false positives if the year in the string was 2010, because it contains 01. Is there a way to make the regex only match the 2 digit years if they are the last 2 digits of a 4 digit year, or are not preceded by 2 digits?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Java as follows

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?:Fits )?(97|1997)?(?:[^0-9]+)?(01|02|200[12]) Ford Explorer.");
// add code to iterate lines
String s = "Fits 1997-2002 Ford Explorer.";
Matcher m = patt.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()){
    if(m.group(1) != null){
        //validate year 1997
    }
    if(m.group(2) != null){
        //validate year 2002
    }
}
```